# How to consider the login function collecting requirements of an application? is it a user requirement?

Tags: documentation, requirements, uml, use-case, requirements-management

I am working on an application that expected to the user logs in when the application is started (as for example it is in Skype: the user open the application and appear to him a login mask when he insert the username and password to start work with the application)

Now I am preparing some use case diagram and I am collecting the application requirements (I have to write some documentation)

Can I consider it as a user requirement? Or what is it?

Answer (score 1):

Become a customer's request when the customer wants the user can authenticate into application.

As a result, in the **architecture diagrams** and in **use cases diagrams**, you must consider this.

It becomes a key element even **for testing**, and **QA**. In the work-flow of the application, you'll definitely consider cases involving the authentication process (*permitted access, user name and password wrong, suspended accounts, and other*).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, what else would it be?  Some applications do not require it, the user/customer wants it, it's a user requirement.

Now, that said, I would strongly urge you to push the user towards some kind of federated/openid login -- even if you have to develop a seperate login app.  This will allow your main application to get out of the business of dealing with login information, username, password, user information security, password reset, etc.

As an additional bonus, it will make it clear that, yes, indeed, logging in, is a user requirement.

Answer (score 1):

It is a user requirement:

1) Security is a user requirement: "I don't want other people to see my data."

2) Work flow is a user requirement: "Don't show me web pages or commands that are not part of my responsibility."

3) Good support is a user requirement: Help Desk: "What page are you on?" User: "The one with the big you can't do that message".

4) Auditing is a user requirement: "Who changed that record?"